# invalid create method

Tags: magento2, model, resource-model, create

I have a model, I call it in a block and when I use the create method I get an error saying: 
`Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Vendor\Namespace\Model\Modelname::create`

The Block (`/app/code/Vendor/Namespace/Block/Blockname.php`) look like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Vendor\Namespace\Model\Modelname $modelFactory,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getAllJohns(){
    $modelFactory = $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection();
}
```

The Model (`/app/code/Vendor/Namespace/Model/Modelname.php`) looks like this:

```
const CACHE_TAG = 'namespace_Modelname';
protected $_cacheTag = 'vendor_namespace_modelname';
protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_namespace_modelname';

protected function _constructor() {
    $this->_init('Vendor\Namespace\Model\ResourceModel\Modelname');
}
//lots of getters and setters down here
```

of course it extends: `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel`. And implements 2  interfaces 1 custom and the other one is `Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface`.

Then we have the resourcemodel (`/app/code/Vendor/Namespace/Model/ResourceModel/Modelname.php`):

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
) {
      parent::__construct($context);
}

protected function _construct() {
    $this->_init('vendor_namespace_model', 'id');
}
```

And it extends `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb`

and last but not least the collection (`/app/code/Vendor/Namespace/Model/ResourceModel/Modelname/Collection.php`):

```
protected $_idFieldName = 'id';
protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_namespace_modelname';
protected $_eventObject = 'modelname_collection';

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('Vendor\Namespace\Model\Modelname',
'Vendor\Namespace\Model\ResourceModel\Modelname');
}
```

and yes it extends `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection`

The rest should be good because if i change the function getAllJohns to return a function from the model that returns a string there is no error/conflict and I can see the string:

```
public function getAllJohns(){
    $modelFactory = $this->_modelFactory->sayHello(); // returns hello
}
```

So far i have tried to rebuild the module, follow multiple tutorials, look at other models in the app, cache:clean, cache:flush, setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile. ( error.log is empty )

Comment: notice that protected function _constructor() { in the modelname.php should be protected function _construct()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use class as a factory you need to suffix your model class with Factory like below.

```
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Vendor\Namespace\Model\ModelnameFactory $modelFactory,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Then defined your function like below

```
public function getAllJohns(){
   $modelFactory = $this->_modelFactory->create()->sayHello(); // returns hello
}
```

Let me know if any further explanation needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, silly me didn't notice it at all. since you are such a good help do you mind if I ask you another question. Now I get the error `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Model collection resource name is not defined.` Do you see any other mistakes I have made in de code in the question

Comment: in which line you got this error

Comment: I found the error by myself and posted in a comment under the question but still thanks!